# how can I get the arguments list of a method from another function under PHP?

Tags: php

If I have a class like this :

```
class A {
    public function method1($arg1, $arg2){}
}
```

and now, I need to do something like this :

```
/**
 * @return array The list of arguemnt names
 */
function getMethodArgList(){
    return get_method_arg_list(A, method1);
}
```

so, how could I implement the function getMethodArgList() ? any one could help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure if I get the question, but [ReflectionClass](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and ReflectionMethod might be what you're looking for.

e.g.

```
<?php
var_dump(getMethodArgList());

class A {
    public function method1($arg1, $arg2){}
}

function getMethodArgList() {
    $rc = new ReflectionClass('A');
    $rm = $rc->getMethod('method1');
    return $rm->getParameters();
}
```

prints

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  class ReflectionParameter#3 (1) {
    public $name =>
    string(4) "arg1"
  }
  [1] =>
  class ReflectionParameter#4 (1) {
    public $name =>
    string(4) "arg2"
  }
}
```

To get only the names you can use

```
return array_map(function($e) { return $e->getName(); }, $rm->getParameters());
```

instead of `return $rm->getParameters();`

Comment: thank you so much, I was just stuck at $rm = rc->getMethod('method1'); I don't know what else to do after this... anyaway, thank you.